# Use Protractor without testing framework

Tags: webdriver, protractor

Is it possible to integrate Protractor into a simple browser automation tool by referencing it and add some webdriver & browser initialization code? 
The cli interface of the `protractor conf.js` is quite well documented but it depends on jasmine or other testing frameworks.

Are there any examples out there which could save me some time?
Something like the following would be great:

```
//require protractor
var client = new Protractor(settings etc.);
client.browser.start();
client.driver.element.by....click() ;
```

I do not want to use Protractors interactive shell or its on top TCP socket for my application.

Comment: Could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518694/how-to-run-protractor-as-a-script-and-not-as-a-child-process-or-using-a-task-run.

Comment: I was not able to integrate protractor into my application but I could integrate my app into protractor via its custom framework extension point. Luckily for my use case it is okay to let protractor be the "parent" app. I used https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/frameworks/README.md as starting point.