# How to run protractor from code with arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

i have 2 projects:

- project 1: in this project i am trying to run project 2
- project 2: this is a proctractor project - in my config file i have params like: "param1, param2"

In project 1 I am trying to run protractor from project 2.

```
const Launcher = require("project1/protractor/built/launcher");
Launcher.init('path/to/project1/conf');
```

How can i add some arguments like: "--params.param1=test" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring your code -

```
const Launcher = require("project1/protractor/built/launcher");
Launcher.init('path/to/project1/conf');
```

If you are using init then it takes two parameters

```
init(configFile: string, additionalConfig: Config)
```

You can import already created config file from the project1 like
const config = require('./config'); or whatever path you have.

Once it is imported then update params and pass entire config object to init function.

```
config.params.param1=test123456'
Launcher.init('path/to/project1/conf', config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your config file

```
  params: {
        login: {
          username: "user007",
          password: "user007"
        }
      }
```

Now you update the `username` from cmd as below.

```
npm  run --params.login.username = 'user008' --params.login.password=`user008` //This will overwrite the `user007`
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: i have 'param1' in my config file.
I want overwrite it from my launcher.init like this:
`Launcher.init('path/to/conf --params.param1=test123456');`

Comment: Could you share your config file?

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem so i edited the question.

Comment: I want to do it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518694/how-to-run-protractor-as-a-script-and-not-as-a-child-process-or-using-a-task-run

but with parameters